# How to define custom JavaScript Complexity Rules in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, code-complexity

I have read through the complexity documentation via [SonarQube Metrics Definition](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Complexity). I have also dug through the Rules we have defined, but those only determine bugs in the code & their respective severity. Unfortunately it does not outline how we could go about defining custom complexity rules (i.e. if you do x, the complexity will be increased by 1).

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question didn't originally specify language, so for

- Java - [Writing Custom Java Rules 101](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101).
- JavaScript - [Custom Rules for SonarJS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+SonarJS)
- PHP - [Custom Rules for PHP](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+PHP)
- COBOL - [Custom rules for COBOL](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+COBOL)

These are brief tutorials to bootstrap rule writing. In writing your own rules, you'll likely have questions of the "How do I get to X?" nature. With those, you should open a new thread on the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube).

Comment: oops you're right! I meant to mention it is for a JavaScript project. Updated the question. - Thank you very much for the link though! I found the JS version of the link you provided. Is there a specific are you could point me to in regards to complexity? I'm still fairly new to Sonar

Comment: Head over to the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) for that @SeanRamzan

Answer (score 0):

On https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+SonarJS, it says

**Custom rules**

> This feature is deprecated

As a replacement, we suggest you to have a look at ESLint, it provides custom rules that you can then import thanks to the External Issues feature.